# How to explode row in table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

i have these row in table

K04, K84, K53, K331, L985

how i can do with array explode to get result like :

['K04','K84','K53','K331','L985']

thanks for any help...

i tried to using explode,

```
      $ex    = explode (' ,' $myRowFromTable)
      $co    = count ($ex);

      for ($i = 0; $i < $co; $i++)
      {
       echo $ex[$i];
       }
```

result only show K04

Comment: Do want to have the result in MySQL instead of the original? Or in PHP in array or in a string?

Comment: what you are tring to acheive? `explode()` will give the result like you want.

Comment: I have edit my question, i have tried with explode.

Comment: @pitokeraf, I don't know hows you get result, even your codes are buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to convert String to JavaScript Array. Take a look for Example;

```
$myRowFromTable = 'K04, K84, K53, K331, L985';
// Has Array Data
$ex = explode (', ', $myRowFromTable);
// print_r($ex);

// According to User Expected Result
$newFormat = "['" . implode("', '", $ex) . "']";
echo $newFormat;
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://codepad.org/BtLj3cdY)</kbd>

Comment: how I can join K04, K84, K53 etc to another table to get the item name? thnks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using explode as below assuming you are getting the values as a string in `$myRowFromTable`:

```
$ex = explode (',', $myRowFromTable);  //no space before comma
```

Comment: are you sure this will work? Should be `explode (',', $myRowFromTable);`

Comment: @jogesh_pi haha...yes...that won't work...missed a comma myself... :D ..updating..